# in php set limit to the size of the image (in MB or KB)

Tags: php

I have the following php code, which allows user to upload an image. How can I modify my code so that there will be a limit (lets say maximun 800 k) to the size of the image uploaded. Here is my code.

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['profile'])===true) {
    if (empty($_FILES['profile']['name']) === true) {
        echo'Please choose an Image File !';
    } else {
        $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');                            
        $file_name = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
        $file_extn = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        $file_temp = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name']; 

        if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true) {
            change_profile_image($session_user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn);
            header('Location: ' . $current_file);  
            exit();
        } else {
            echo'Incorrect file type! Allowed:';
            echo implode(', ', $allowed);
        }
    }
}

if (empty($user_data['profile'])=== false ) {
    echo '<img src="', $user_data['profile'], '" alt="', $user_data['name'], ' - Profile Image">';   
}
?>
```

Comment: You should enforce the limit at the server config level, e.g. php.ini `post_max_size`.

Comment: @MarcB There are many valid reasons not to. You may not have access to the constant, or the max upload size may vary amongst several forms in the same application, or you may simply want to throw a nicer error than "THE MAXIMUM UPLOAD SIZE WAS EXCEEDED" on a white screen. Also, it should be `upload_max_filesize` as well as `post_max_size`.

Comment: @niels: you can still check for that via the `['error']` parameter. But in general it's better to NOT allow an oversize upload in the first place.

Comment: @MarcB Configs should guard against server limit violations, not application constraints. If Facebook wants profile pictures to be max 64KB, it would be ridiculous to impose the limit by config as it would render photo uploads unusable. The purpose of the config limits is to avoid DOS-attacks by uploading a ton of 1GB files to clog up the server and its temp storage folders.

Comment: why? you can quite easy set the limit per-script, e.g. `<file "upload.php">php_value post_max_size 4096</file>`. just because one part of a site needs a lower limit doesn't mean that limit has to be applied to the ENTIRE site.

Comment: And now members with a reputation over 100 of registered over 30 days are allowed to upload a larger photo, how do I solve that in the vhost definition? The point is moot, there are many valid reasons to enforce max upload size in code, as well as maintaining server integrity maximums by config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amending your code to handle the check, you would just need to add the following statement

```
if ($_FILES['profile']['size'] > 800*1024) {
    echo 'File size too large';
} else {
    // your code for processing uploaded image
}
```

For example

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['profile'])===true) {
    if (empty($_FILES['profile']['name']) === true) {
        echo'Please choose an Image File !';
    } else {
        if ($_FILES['profile']['size'] > 800*1024) {
            echo 'File size too large';
        } else {
            $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');                            
            $file_name = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
            $file_extn = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $file_temp = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name']; 

            if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true) {
                change_profile_image($session_user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn);
                header('Location: ' . $current_file);  
                exit();
            } else {
                echo'Incorrect file type! Allowed:';
                echo implode(', ', $allowed);
            }
        }
    }
}

if (empty($user_data['profile'])=== false ) {
    echo '<img src="', $user_data['profile'], '" alt="', $user_data['name'], ' - Profile Image">';   
}
?>
```

Although at this point, with this many nested `if` statements I would start to look at tidying this up into some upload functions or possibly a class.

An alternative route is to set the MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden input in your form, then check the error value of the `$_FILES` for a `2`

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="819200" />
```

PHP

```
if ($_FILES['profile']['error'] == 2) {
    die('File too large');
} else {
    // upload code
}
```

Obviously this solution can be circumvented by someone with Firebug or Web Inspector etc changing the value before form post

Comment: I did and I get no error messages, but when I try to upload a large image I get the error message  "Warning: POST Content-Length of 20155721 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: You're getting that erro because your PHP is configured with the default value of `post_max_size` of 8MB (8388608) and you tried to upload what appears to be a file of 19MB (20155721).  PHP is throwing an error before your script is completing.  Check out the rest of the error codes (you can use `1` for file exceeds php.ini setting) [upload_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: I have used else if ($_FILES['profile']['size'] > 800*1024) { echo 'File size too large';} The truth is that I dont get any error messages now, but when I try to upload an Image i.e 19 mb I get the warning error from php. If my code worked fine then I shouldn't get the warning message from php. Is that right?

Comment: No that's not right.  As per previous comment, the warning is due to PHP on your host being configure to only accept uploads up to 8MB.  If you try to upload anything larger, the PHP code will choke and issue the warning before it ever parses your `if` statement

Answer (score 1):

[According to the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> `$_FILES['userfile']['size']`
>
> The size, in bytes, of the uploaded file.

To use this:

```
if($_FILES['profile']['size'] > $limit)
     die('Too large!');`
```

Alternatively you could of course do:

```
if(filesize($_FILES['profile']['tmp_name']) > $limit)
     die('Too large!');`
```

Comment: I have copy and paste the code but I get an error message with the ">". Any idea ?

Comment: Was a sparse `)` in there, fixed it.

Comment: variable $limit how should be defined?

Comment: `$limit = 800*1024;` to enforce an 800KB limit (800 times 1024 bytes).

Comment: I did it, but the image which is more that 800*1024 is still uploaded, without being displayed (I get an empty frame). The message 'Too large!' still not displayed

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
$_FILES["file"]["size"] - the size in bytes of the uploaded file
```

Source:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: This answer is wrong - the `size` member of the array is in bytes, not kilobytes. Also, [never trust W3Schools](http://www.w3fools.com), it's not a reputable source for anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_FILES['uploaded_file']['size']
```

should give you the size of the file. You can use an if statement

```
$_FILES['uploaded_file']['type']
```

if you want to check the type of file uploaded

Comment: From the manual on the `['type']` member: *"The mime type of the file, if the browser provided this information. An example would be "image/gif". This mime type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore don't take its value for granted."*

Comment: Right.. but pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) checks the extension or just give the extension of the file that was sent ?

Comment: Doesn't check anything either but at least you don't get a false sense of security. They're actually both equally unreliable, browsers also guess the MIME type by checking a magic list of file extensions. Bottom line: never trust user input.