# How to Reduce Image size to 20kB on upload?

Tags: php, image-processing, uploadify

I need Clients to upload their images on a form. But the image size shouldn't exceed 20kB. How do i implement this so that the clients need not worry about size. But when it is uploaded it should be <20kB. Reducing image size after uploading to server is OK.

The requirement is 20kb or less (Strictly). So resizing images and hoping for it to be 20kb is not a good idea.
I'm already using 'Uploadify'. So solutions related to it would be really great.
Thanks in advance guys!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423551/in-php-set-limit-to-the-size-of-the-image-in-mb-or-kb

Comment: You could reduce the size (width/height) or increase compression rate depending on the format you're using.

Comment: use any image resizer to resize the image and reduce its size

Comment: @user2071225: I want to accept whatever the file client uploads and then resize it myself (server side ofcourse!). Dont want to display "File size too large" to them.